# Illustrator: How do I retain Pantone 4975C when saving an AI and PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pdf, spot-color

[image]

[image]

I inherited a design master file of several labels that has a Pantone color. However when I copy and paste one label I need into a new ai file to be saved as a PDF for printing... I get the error message "unexpected results"

How do I retain that color or convert it to a spot color for printing?

[ACTUAL FILE STRIPPED to JUST CORE COLORS](http://aworkofmarc.com/1/YALF-1_5oz-GRABGO-FRONT_stackexchange.ai)

Comment: Does the file have a spot color interacting with transparency? Opacity?
 Blend modes? Etc. Select All and what does `Object > Flatten Transparency` show as a preview? (that's a **warning** not an error - only alerting to to *possible* issues. It doesn't mean there *is* an issue.)

Comment: I added a link to a stripped down version of the file above.  It would appear when I select the object with the Pantone color in question and do as you mentioned "Object > Flatten Transparency" that it saves correctly (?) At least without throwing any errors messages... So I'

Comment: doubled posted sorry.

Comment: Should I select preserve alpha transparency when saving?

Comment: Sorry. Strike my previous reply.  I'm STILL getting the same error as mentioned in the original post  IF I paste it into a new blank AI document and then try to save.  I do not get that error if I save it in its original file.

Comment: How is the job being printed?  Is this 4 colour process lithography + spot colours, or is it for digital printing?  If you add another spot colour, you will end up with a 6 colour print job. Are you really sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is a **warning**. It is **not** an error.

Illustrator presents this warning whenever you have spot color mixed with other color (CMYK or RGB). Even if everything is fine in the file.

What Illustrator is alerting you to is that there *may be* a change in colors **if** you used **any transparency** in the file and a spot color interacts with that transparency. Transparency constitutes anything with utilizes an **opacity** setting or a **blend mode**.

If you have no such interactions, then the warning is **just a warning** and you can ignore it.

This warning **does not** mean there is a problem with the file. It is just telling you to **check** the file. Illustrator can't check the file for you. All Illustrator knows is that there is transparency *somewhere* and there is a spot color *somewhere* in the file. Illustrator does not know if the spot color actually interacts with the transparency. The warning is **not** referencing any color usage, it's referencing **transparency** usage. You need to check that.

What happens when spot color interacts with transparency is that the output will use CMYK to blend the appearance colors. You can't place a 100C 50% transparent object on top of a solid pantone color and expect to retain the solid pantone color by default -- you would need to adjust knockouts or overprints.

An easy way to check transparency in any file is to `Select > All`, then choose `Object > Flatten Transparency` and tick the `Preview` box. Look at what the preview does to the artwork (don't click OK, just look). Or use the **Flattener Preview Panel** (Window > Flattener Preview) to see where transparency is in the file. Those are the elements where transparency is a factor.

The file you linked to appears fine, although it is a **5 color** piece of art (CMYK+1). But then, I'm not getting the warning with it either. So I think you may have removed something which may have been triggering the warning.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for taking the time for such detailed and thorough answer.